# How to convert Excel spreadsheet 2007 to pdf in Linux

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office

There is no cute pdf writer. How can i convert excel spreadsheet 2007
 to pdf in linux

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate to a question which is asking about how to convert `ODT` file to a pdf? While this question is about excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 12):

You can use Libreoffice Calc (always work on a copy)
. Open the file and Export as pdf.

Also you could run from the command line

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.xlsx
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is the preinstalled print to file printer, if you selct file print you should see that.  Print to file will create a PDF as well.  (Basically just like cute PDF)

Chris